# What is appropriate way of "parsing" string of certain format in Perl?

Tags: perl

I wrote very fancy and pretty customizable bash prompt (`PS1`), just in my `.bashrc`.
So after I finished the "code" turned to be very messy and how prompt was customized wasn't very nice too (it worked though).

I've come up with an idea to "describe" how I want my prompt to look like with a certain string i.e. `"|> user |> hostname |> pwd |> git_status |>"` would generate a simple powerline-like prompt ("|>" would be "mapped" to triangle symbol I thought).

I've decided that using Perl might be good for this kind of task, however I know too little about Perl and am not too experienced with it. So I thought I just might ask experienced users about how would I "parse" a string like that in the example above via Perl.

Allowed symbol strings may be different e.g: '|>', '|)', '|/' or '|\', and would generate different symbols. Also prompt string may not contain any of those at all. The text would indicate command to be executed to get contents for part of the prompt.

Comment: You could do that with a regex grammar. Or by splitting on a pattern like `my @foo = split /( \|/ (?:[>)/\\] ) )x, $str and then use a dispatch table (a hash with subs in it) for each thing.

Comment: Or have you considered using https://ohmyz.sh/

Comment: I originally wrote about that in my question but decided to cut it out later. I'm not using any existing popular prompt implementations because they don't fit my needs, they are not enough customizable to me, or simply are bloat. I have very custom git status command for prompt and also logic for showing mounted device on a directory and other more advanced stuff like that. So I decided to make my own prompt. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
use open OUT => ':encoding(UTF-8)', ':std';

use Term::ANSIColor;

my %symbol = (
    user       => '\\u',
    hostname   => colored('\\h', 'cyan'),
    pwd        => '\\w',
    git_status => colored('$(echo OK)', 'green'),
    '|>'       => '▶');


my $string = shift;

my $re = join '|', map quotemeta, sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %symbol;
$string =~ s/($re)/$symbol{$1}/g;
print $string;
```

Save as `prompt.pl`, then in bash:

```bash
PS1=$(prompt.pl '|> user |> hostname |> pwd |> git_status |>')
```